# Opencv2 and python - cv2 detects different RGB values

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, colors, rgb

I'm drawing a line with a specific color (RGB), after that I load an image with opencv2 in Python and convert the BGR to RGB.

Unfortunately the array I'm getting from opencv2 has slightly different RGB values.

It doesn't matter if I use Illustrator or Paint. JPG, PNG, BMP or TIF. The color always differs from +- 1 to 40.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

src = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
image = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print(image[10, 10])
```

My input has been a square with the RGB values `[100 50 0]` and I'm getting `[95 46 0]`, but I need the exact RGB values.

Comment: If you want exact values, try using a loss-less format like PNG or TIFF.

Comment: As i already wrote, I used JPG, TIFF, PNG and BMP. Makes no difference.

Comment: Can you share the file you created - preferably as a PNG please? Maybe it has a coour profile which OpenCV is ignoring.

Comment: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/170104/aerv3qua.png given values [100 50 0] and I got [98 52 14]

Comment: I suspect ImageReady is colour managing your image. I only use Photoshop, not ImageReady, but I think you need to find an option called `Color Management` and make sure it is set to `off`. It may be near `Assign Color Profile` or similar.

Comment: Well, it just had been the presettings of the document. Now everything's fine!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you save your input, from whichever program you are using. I tried opening your example image with an image editing program, and values are the same with what I got from your code in OpenCV.

Try saving the input like the following, and re-read with your code. If it still differs, then we can be consider the problem is related with `imread` or `cvtColor`. The values at A, B, and C must be the same. Also make sure that you are saving in a lossless format.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Create a constant image
img = np.ones((15,15,3))
img[:,:,0]=100
img[:,:,1]=50
img[:,:,2]=0
# Check the desired value = A
print(img[10,10])
# Save the image
cv2.imwrite("input.png",img)

# Read back the image
src=cv2.imread("input.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
# Check the desired value = B
print(src[10,10])

# Convert the image
image = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# Check the desired value = C
print(image[10, 10])
```